# $\mathbb{R}^n$ with countably many points removed is simply connected

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I was using Van Kampen's Theorem and induction to show that $\mathbb{R}^n$ with finitely many points removed is simply connected for $n\geq 3$. However, this made me wonder whether we can remove countably many points and get the same conclusion. I'm not sure how I would go about proving it, nor can I think of a counterexample. I'm not even sure whether $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\mathbb{Q}^n$ is simply connected.

Comment: It's pretty easy to see that $ \mathbb{R}^n \backslash \mathbb{Q}^n$ is simply connected for $n \geq 2$. Think of them as lots of (hyper)planes that are connected together.

Comment: @CalvinLin Do you mean $n\geq 3$?

Comment: @CalvinLin I assume you mean $n\geq 3$. I get the idea would be to homotope a loop into one of the hyperplanes with an irrational coordinate, but I don't find it obvious how to do that.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \mathbb{Q}^n$ is path-connected via lines with at least one irrational coordinate. However, path-connectedness is just the "easy" part of proving something is simply connected

Comment: Ah, I missed out the 2nd part.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Yea, I'm familiar with that fact. It's partially what inspired me to ask this question.

Comment: Possibly you can invoke the proof in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1186988 replacing the word "finite" with "countable".

Comment: @ChrisCulter I'm not sure that proof works. It appears he uses the fact that $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus X$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ when $X$ is finite, but this fails if $X$ is countable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is simply connected. See the proof given [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/215923/is-mathbbr3-setminus-mathbbq3-simply-connected): It will apply to any countable subset of any simply-connected topological manifold of dimension $\ge 3$. A related MSE question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1188062/why-is-the-complement-of-a-discrete-subspace-of-mathbbrn-n-ge-3-simpl).